# How do I remove NLP from Tika?

Tags: apache-tika

I just want to extract data from documents. So I do not think I need OpenNLP.

Is there a way to easily take it out so my Tika is lighter?

Comment: How do you use Apache Tika? The java libraries via Maven? Via Gradle? Tika App? Other?

Comment: Maven is what I use.

Comment: Why not just exclude the nlp dependency when you pull in Tika Parsers in the usual way?

Comment: The usual way? That's why I am asking. I am looking for the best and easiest way. I am kinda of new to Maven I understand some of the basic concept.

Comment: Did you try https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html ?

Comment: It seems to be quite integrated in Tika. In tika-parser it is included in the pom.xml. Also how do I exclude this: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-parsers/pom.xml#L729

Comment: Also they don't have <optional> element...

Answer (score 0):

I have same need just like you.The way I deal with it is that I delete the module directly.In my program I delete the NLP and NL module and it works normally.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I was wandering if there was a easy way to do it with Maven.

Comment: You can ignore the program you don't need in the IEDA.